# Rear audiojack not working with any audio device (need for headphones)

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones

I'm having some trouble with my audio here. My old headphone jack broke inside the front audio input (I've long since given up on fixing that) so I'm merely trying to use another set of headphones in the rear audio jack. However, nothing seems to be working. Now, to clarify, I am a complete idiot when it comes to computer and might need some idiot-proof instructions if you would be so kind.

I'm running a 32-bit Windows 7 Enterprise on an Antec listed as "ACPI x86-based PC". My audio driver is just listed as "high definition audio device" provided by Microsoft. It is worth noting that when I plug my headphones in and go to "Playback devices", my headphones do not get listed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the broken headphone plug still stuck in the front audio jack? If so, that's probably issue. If Windows detects that something is plugged into the headphone jack on the front, it will mute the output to the speaker jack on the back.

Another possibility is that the jack is damaged so that either the L or R right is bent and touching another contact, causing Windows to think the jack is occupied.

Depending on your device and driver, you may have the option to disable headphone jack detection and use the rear outputs exclusively. If you have Realtek HD Audio Manager, open it (right click the reddish orange speaker icon in the system tray), go to Connector Settings, and tick the box for "Disable front panel jack detection" as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]